# Oracle fast formula condition to compare only the timestamp part

Tags: oracle, logic, bi-publisher

I am creating an Oracle fast formula, I need to check the time between 06:00 AM and 12:00 AM  i.e. when the PAY_TIME > 06:00 AM and less than 12:00 AM.

I am using the following -

```
                    L_STARTmin  = TO_CHAR(AISTOPTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

But when I am comparing this to > 06:00:00 the condition is not entering the loop, I am using -

```
IF TO_DATE(L_STARTmin,'HH24:MI:SS')>= TO_DATE('06:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')AND TO_DATE(L_STOPmin,'HH24:MI:SS')<= TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

How can i only compare the date part i.e. if time is 05:00:00 AM then this loop shouldnt be entered, else it should be, how to use the timestamp for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which datatype you used for `l_startmin` and `l_stopmin`. Should be `date` (or `timestamp`). Code you posted suggests different - a `varchar2`, which is wrong - don't store date(time) values in inappropriate datatype columns/variables.

How to extract hour from date value? `sysdate` returns `date` datatype so I'll use it for this example.

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24')) hour_1,
  3         extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) hour_2
  4  from dual;

SYSDATE                 HOUR_1     HOUR_2
------------------- ---------- ----------
12.03.2023 09:13:46          9          9

SQL>
```

If datatype was `varchar2`, then a lot of TO_this and TO_that (first convert string to date, then apply `to_char` to extract hours, and `to_number` it so that you get a numeric representation of *hour* value):

```
SQL> select to_number(to_char(to_date('12.03.2023 09:15:23', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh24')) hour_1
  2  from dual;

    HOUR_1
----------
         9

SQL>
```

---

As you aren't really interested in sub-hour information, code might evaluate to

```
if extract(hour from cast(l_startmin as timestamp)) >= 6 and
   extract(hour from cast(l_stopmin  as timestamp)) <= 12
then ...
```